# Is it a best practice to give generally any node an alias?

Tags: 9

For each node I can create an alias.

I mean to give an alias such as `/abc` alongside the path `/node/1`.

Is it a best practice to give generally any node an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should generally give every node an alias.  The default path of `/node/1` is not good for SEO; it is better to have a few keywords in the URL that describe the content of the page.

### Using a canonical URL

Although you should use aliases, you do not want to present both `/node/1` and `/my-alias-for-node1` to Google; instead, you should set the aliases (if they exist) as the canonical URL.  This can be done automatically by configuring the [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).

If you need to set canonical URLs beyond aliases (for example, if nodes 2 and 3 should actually refer to node 1 as the canonical URL), you can set that up with the [Metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag).

### Automatic alias generation

You can automate creation of aliases with the [Pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), which lets you use tokens to easily generate aliases based on patterns/rules that you choose.